# update state onchange in react

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

Hi i am trying to update state as code below, but not reflecting in my state, when i debug the code the state is changing in console but not updating, I have a initial state where it is displaying in textfield and onchange i trying to update but not updating.

statecontext is defined in initialstate like below.

```
creditCard: {
    isSaved: false,
    lastFourDigits: "1235",
    loading: false,
    cardholder: "",
    cardnumber: "",
    cardmonth: "",
    cardyear: "",
    cardcvv: "",
  },
```

in component:

```
  const { state, actionsCollection } = useContext(StateContext);

 const onChange = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    switch (e.target.name) {
 case "cardmonth":
        state.creditCard.cardmonth = e.target.value.replace(/\D/g, "").slice(0, 2);
        break;
      case "cardyear":
        state.creditCard.cardyear = e.target.value.replace(/\D/g, "").slice(0, 2);
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
  };

<TextField
                    name="cardmonth"
                    label="MM"
                    error={errors.cardmonth}
                    value={state.creditCard.cardmonth}
                    onChange={onChange}
                    onBlur={validateInput}
                    helperText={errors.cardmonth && "Invalid month"}
                    className={classes.expiryDateInputs}
                  />
                  <TextField
                    name="cardyear"
                    label="YY"
                    error={errors.cardyear}
                    value={state.creditCard.cardyear}
                    onChange={onChange}
                    onBlur={validateInput}
                    helperText={errors.cardyear && "Invalid year"}
                    className={classes.expiryDateInputs}
                  />
```

Comment: Why are you using `useContext` here? If you need some data globally then you have to properly use useContext. Check [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext).  The problem here is you are trying to update a variable directly not using react method, hence react is not updating the UI.

Comment: i need data globally so i am using useContext, can you please tell me how to update state

Comment: You have to wrap it with the context provider. See the link above in the comment.

Comment: All that things are done and getting the context in my component, only thing is i need to update initial state with onchange

Comment: you have to define the variable in a state and then pass the setState method in context provider. And finally use that method to update state data.

Comment: can you please update in answer, i am struggling from 1 day

Comment: Check [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/usecontext-example-forked-4vtcb2).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245555/discussion-between-deepak-biswal-and-sudhir).

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like the below. Use the `setState` method to update the state data.

```
const { state, setState} = useState(StateContext);
    
     const onChange = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        switch (e.target.name) {
     case "cardmonth":
            setState({...state, cardmonth: e.target.value.replace(/\D/g, "").slice(0, 2)});
            break;
          case "cardyear":
            setState({...state, cardyear: e.target.value.replace(/\D/g, "").slice(0, 2);
            break;
          default:
            break;
        }
      };
    
    <TextField
                        name="cardmonth"
                        label="MM"
                        error={errors.cardmonth}
                        value={state.creditCard.cardmonth}
                        onChange={onChange}
                        onBlur={validateInput}
                        helperText={errors.cardmonth && "Invalid month"}
                        className={classes.expiryDateInputs}
                      />
                      <TextField
                        name="cardyear"
                        label="YY"
                        error={errors.cardyear}
                        value={state.creditCard.cardyear}
                        onChange={onChange}
                        onBlur={validateInput}
                        helperText={errors.cardyear && "Invalid year"}
                        className={classes.expiryDateInputs}
                      />
```

Comment: i have already defined state in useContext if you see in my code

Comment: if i use setstate like above i am getting error setState is not function